# Qt - How to save a configuration file on multiple platforms

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I'm writing a Qt application that needs to save some settings to the user's configuration directory.

I've come up with the following code to get this folder:

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
    path = QDir::homePath() + "/Application Data/Timely";
#else
    path = QDir::homePath() + "/.config/Timely";
#endif
```

This fails on Windows 7 cause Windows 7 uses App Data/Roaming/[YourApp]. How can I get the user's configuration folder in a cross-platform way? I'm I missing something obvious? (this is supposed to be an easy task)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on the settings you want to record, but I would suggest to use [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is supposed to be an easy task - but you're *not* supposed to hard-code paths. You should use the native APIs on win/mac, and an enviroment variable on most newer unix-like. Of course, Qt helps you do this cross-platform.

Follow Tibur's suggestion and use QSettings if it's configuration data for your Qt app. You can also get the config directory by using the appropriate QT api.

**QT4:** [`QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#storageLocation) 
**QT5:** [`QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstandardpaths.html#writableLocation)

Answer (score 1):

I use [QSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsettings.html) for simple values that make sense to put in the Windows registry or an INI file, and [SQLite](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Creating_an_SQLite_database_in_Qt) for more complicated setups. In Qt5, put the SQLite database in [QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ConfigLocation)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstandardpaths.html#details). In Qt4, put the SQLite database in [QDesktopServices](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/%20qdesktopservices.html) as gnud suggested ([deprecated in Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qdesktopservices-obsolete.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to provided answers suggesting to use QSettings, I will shamelessly copy here Qt's own example from documentation (I slightly edited it, though).

Here are the functions to read and write settings from the file/registry/whatever:

```
void MainWindow::readSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    resize(settings.value("size", QSize(400, 400)).toSize()); // note the 400x400 defaults if there is no saved settings yet
    move(settings.value("pos", QPoint(200, 200)).toPoint()); // here default pos is at 200,200
    settings.endGroup();
}

void MainWindow::writeSettings()
{
    QSettings settings("Moose Soft", "Clipper");

    settings.beginGroup("MainWindow");
    settings.setValue("size", size());
    settings.setValue("pos", pos());
    settings.endGroup();
}
```

The `readSettings()` function may be called from the MainWindow constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    ...
    readSettings();
}
```

while `writeSettings()` from the close event handler:

```
void MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
        writeSettings();
        event->accept();
}
```

Last but not least, take a note, that settings format may be different. For example, if you want settings to be saved in the registry in Windows, you should pass `QSettings::NativeFormat` to the constructor, but if you'd like text config in the `%appdata%`, pass `QSettings::IniFormat` instead. In the example above format isn't passed, so it's native by default.

My personal preference to set `IniFormat` for Windows (because registry data isn't easily transferable) and `NativeFormat` for Linux and macOS, like this:

```
QSettings *settings;

if ( (os == "Linux") | (os == "macOS") ) {
    settings = new QSettings(QSettings::NativeFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "Moose Soft", "Clipper");
} else {
    settings = new QSettings(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "Moose Soft", "Clipper");
};
```